# How to search array of int as property?

Tags: react-native, realm

My Show Object:

```
class Show extends Realm.Object { }
  Show.schema = {
  name: 'Show',
  primaryKey: 'showId',
  properties: {
    showId: 'int',
    showName:{ type: 'string', default: ''  },
    episodes:{ type: 'int[]', default: []  },
   }  
};
```

How then can I search the Show objects via the episodes property?

I have already search here and there and tried:

```
.filtered('episodes == $0',12345)
.filtered('episodes IN $0',12345)
```

but nothing works.

Comment: Because it's not yet supported in any bindings. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334 https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513 https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361  so I guess it's not in JS either

Answer (score 0):

`IN` predicates aren't yet supported, however, there are a couple of workarounds:

**Property Array Contains Value**

If you want to know if an array property on your Realm object contains one or more values, you can't use primitive values like `int[]` in your example. If instead you create an `Episode` schema with an `id` property, you can then do a `filtered('episodes.id == $0', 12345)`.

**Scalar Property in Array**

This can be done by mapping and joining a set of predicates until `IN` is supported which looks something like the following psuedocode:

`.filterted([1,2,3].map(id => 'property == id').join(' OR '))`